# discrete proximity to gaussian distribution using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, convolution, gaussian

I'm trying to get a discrete proximity to a gaussian distribution for n >= 2.

So let's say if n = 2 than the discrete proximity would be [0.5, 0.5].

when n = 3 than it would be [0.25, 0.5, 0.25]

when n = 4 than it would be [0.125, 0.375, 0.375, 0.125]

you get my point I hope.

The returned discrete proximity array sum should always be 1 as all distributions.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import scipy 
from random import randint

def discrete_gauss(n):
    g = [0.5, 0.5]
    f = g
    for x in range(1, n - 1):
        f = np.convolve(f,g)

    if(sum(f) != 1):
        print("The distribution sum is not 1.")
    else:
        return f
```

Now 'discrete_gauss' works great when I use (1 < n < 68) but when I enter (n > 67), the sum of f is different than 1 (sometimes more sometimes less) and I don't know why.
Anyone has any clue?

Sorry for the messy question I tried to keep it short. I'll be happy to clarify things if they are not clear.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you printed the sum. When I run your code with large n I get a sum like `0.9999999999999999` suggesting that your problems is just a floating point precision issue.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yep it some kind of precision problem but I don't know where and why it only happens when n > 67.

Comment: What the heck is a "discrete proximity"? Do you mean that you want to approximate a continuous gaussian distribution as a discrete distribution with `n` points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Read this [paper](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) about the challenges of using floating point math, and then reconsider your approach.

## Solution

Here's an alternative procedure for generating your desired "distribution" that avoids the floating point rounding errors in the summation that `np.convolve` performs:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as sps

def discrete_gauss(n):
    f = np.array([sps.comb(n - 1, i, exact=True) for i in range(n)], dtype='O')
    f = np.float64(f)/np.float64(f).sum()

    if not np.allclose(f.sum(), 1.0):
        raise ValueError("The distribution sum is not close to 1.\n" 
                         "f.sum(): %s" % f.sum())

    return f
```

## Explanation of solution

The sequence you want is equivalent to the `n`th level of Pascal's triangle (see figure at the top of the [Wiki on Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)), normalized so that it can represent a probability. The above solution uses standard Python `int` values (which are arbitrary precision by default in Python 3) to find the values in the `n`th level, then switches to floating point math only at the very end for the normalization step (ie `np.float64(f)/np.float64(f).sum()`).

Note the use of `not np.allclose(f.sum(), 1.0)` in the check above, instead of `f.sum() != 1.0`. As discussed below in the **Deeper dive** section, `f.sum()` will be equal to `1.0` for ~90% of the values of `n` from 1-1000. However, in general you cannot assume that the result of a floating point computation will exactly match the result you'd get from an equivalent computation using real numbers (see this [paper](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for all of the gory details). When dealing with floats you should usually (by which I mean almost always) check that a result is close (*ie* equal to within a given tolerance/error) to your expected value, rather than equal to it.

## Deeper dive

This solution isn't perfect. Most values of `n` produce results that exactly sum to `1.0`, but some don't. The following code checks the results of `discrete_gauss(n)` for values of `n` from 1-1000:

```
nnot1 = []
for n in range(1,1001):
    if discrete_gauss(n).sum() != 1.0:
        nnot1.append(n)

print('discrete_gauss(n).sum() was not equal to 1.0 for %d values of n.' % len(nnot1))
print(nnot1)
```

Output:

```
discrete_gauss(n).sum() was not equal to 1.0 for 75 values of n.
[78, 89, 110, 114, 125, 127, 180, 182, 201, 206, 235, 248, 273, 342, 346, 348, 365, 373, 383, 390, 402, 403, 421, 427, 429, 451, 454, 471, 502, 531, 540, 556, 558, 574, 579, 584, 587, 595, 600, 609, 617, 631, 633, 647, 648, 651, 657, 669, 674, 703, 705, 728, 731, 763, 765, 772, 778, 783, 798, 816, 837, 852, 858, 860, 861, 867, 874, 877, 906, 912, 941, 947, 959, 964, 972]
```

Thus, for ~8% of these values, `dicrete_gauss(n).sum()` was not exactly equal to `1.0`. However, since no error was raised, `np.allclose(dicrete_gauss(n).sum(), 1.0)` was always `True`.

## Notes

- [`scipy.speical.comb(n, k, exact=True)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html) gives the `(n, k)`th binomial coefficient as a standard Python `int`, which is equivalent to the `k`th value in the `n`th level of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Thank you! it works great. Do you mind elaborating a bit about the floating point problem I had and why your solution doesn't encounter one?